# How do I pass props to child without the use of modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal: send a property to a child from a parent component and rendering it.

Problem:

1. I am not able to use modules, for example I am not using npm, meaning require is unavailable to me. Example: `import ChildComponent from 'someLocation';`
2. Parent and child components exist in different files.
3. I am trying to send props from the parent to the child.

Note:

- I am in a situation where I do not understand why I am not able to send props to the child component.
- I am fully aware that if I put the Child component in the Parent's component file, I am able to send the props I need to the Child. The problem is, if I have a Root > Child > Child > Child > Child situation, it becomes unfeasible (to me) to maintain everything in one file. Feel free to share your opinion otherwise.

Example:

- Child Component, existing in `src/parent/child/index.js`

```
const Child = ({ name }) => {
    return (
        // name is undefined!
        <div>{name}, I am the child component</main>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Child),
    document.querySelector('#Child')
);
```

- Parent Component, existing in `src/parent/index.js`

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const name = "Giggles";

        return (
            <div>
                <div id="Child" name={name}></div>
            </div>
        );
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Parent),
    document.querySelector('#Parent')
);
```

- index.html (in pseudocode):

```
<html>
    <head>dependencies in here, react, react-dom and babeljs</head>
    <body>
        <div id="Parent"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="src/parent/index.js"></script>
    <script src="src/parent/child/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: when you mean you can't use `npm`, do you mean you can't use `node` at all? how are you compiling the JSX?

Comment: I am able to compile JSX by using babelJS from the `<script>` in the `<head>` element

Comment: I am also able to use a lower version of node, one that is quite behind and does not have require, so I am stuck without the ability to use `import` or `export` :(

Comment: If you can't import OR export, then you just can't React.

Comment: @markmoxx not true at all, the usage of React is not dependant on modules

Comment: @azium You're right, my statement isn't true, but you'll have a much harder time creating anything decent if these are your limitations.

Comment: `require` is available in every version of Node. `import` and `export` is what's *not* supported in Node in older versions (not sure if it is today). So what you are saying doesn't make sense. Please clarify your issue. Also this has nothing to do with npm (which is a module registry).

Comment: @FelixKling would it help if I change the name of the question to something not related to npm, but rather to not using a 'package manager'?

Comment: It would be more correct to say that you don't want to use modules at all, i.e. no module *system*. But this doesn't have anything to do with React in particular, it just how JavaScript works in the browser.

Comment: Fixed the statement of the question accordingly, thanks @FelixKling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could actually change the order of scripts at the bottom of the `<html>` tag to this:

```
<html>
    <head>dependencies in here, react, react-dom and babeljs</head>
    <body>
        <div id="Parent"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="src/parent/child/index.js"></script>
    <script src="src/parent/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Thus you will be able to access the `Child` variable in the file with `Parent` class, so passing props would as simple as the code below:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const name = "Giggles";

        return (
            <div>
                <Child name={name} />
            </div>
        );
    );
};
```

Also, you should delete ReactDOM rendering in the file where the Child is located, so it will look like this:

```
const Child = ({ name }) => {
    return (
        // name is undefined!
        <div>{name}, I am the child component</main>
    );
};
```

Comment: Nice first answer!

Comment: I am amazed it is this simple, it takes me back to my first days of reactjs, great way to get started on the community, welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This is a really bizarre limitation.. You say "please understand", but I don't so I think you should explain why. It might help get you to a better solution.

The issue here is twofold:

1) Your Parent component isn't actually rendering your child, you just have a div with the `id` of Child which is meaningless in React.

2) The script where your Parent component lives needs access to the Child component somehow, and without a module bundler you'll need to put it on a namespace that can be reached like `window`

3) You are rendering two React trees. To pass props from one component to another they must be in the same render tree.

```
const Child = ({ name }) => {
    return (
        <div>{name}, I am the child component</main>
    );
};


window.Child = Child
```

--

```
const Child = window.Child

class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const name = "Giggles";

        return (
            <div>
                <Child name={name} />
            </div>
        );
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Parent),
    document.querySelector('#Parent')
);
```

Comment: Very useful honestly, your description of what is wrong was flawless and I got a better understanding of my mistakes. I gave the answer to d3byte because of the suggestion about the scripts. Thanks for your time!